# ActiveSupport::Inflector in a Ramaze project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, ramaze

I just upgraded to ActiveSupport 3 and lost all my string methods like "camelize", "titleize", and the like. It broke things all over my project, and so far I've fixed them by re-writing those methods myself, but there has to be a better way. I do realize that it's probably a good thing that ActiveSupport no longer monkey patches String globally, but, it was working great for *me*. Is there anyway I can patch these things back onto string, of find a new way to call them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably doing this:

```
require 'active_support'
```

Which requires the very, very basics of Active Support.

What you want is this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually had to require a couple things. Seems a little hacky... but at least it works now!

    require 'active_support/lazy_load_hooks'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/string'